# Collatz sequence algorithm not working right

Tags: c++, algorithm

For some reason, this always returns value 1. The point of this is to find the starting number (1-1,000,000) that loops the most amount of times (until j = 1). **j will always end up being 1 eventually (collatz theory)**, I divide j by 2 if it's even, or multiple by 3 and add 1 if it's odd.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int collatz() {
int counter = 0;
int holder = 0;

for (int i = 999999; i > 1; i--){           // loops 999,999 times
    for (int j = i; j != 1; counter++) {    // loops until j = 1, records amount of loops
        if (j % 2 == 0) {                   // if j is even, divide by 2, +1 to counter
            j = j / 2;
        } else {
            j = (j*3) + 1;                  // if j is odd, multiply by 3 and add 1, +1 to counter
        }
    }
    if (holder < counter){          // records highest number of loops
    holder = counter;
    counter = 0;
    } else {
    counter = 0;
    }


}
    return holder;
}

int main()
{
    cout << collatz << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If my memory serves correctly, you might need to use `long long` even in that range, as the temporary variable `j` can grow a lot and therefore overflow before it's reduced to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not *calling* your function, you're printing out the function pointer (which is converted to the `bool` value `true` (i.e. `1`)).

Comment: Ah thanks, but now it doesn't work at all when I call it. Is it because it's too much to process?

Comment: this is a good interview puzzle. I notice the odd thing in mainafter staring at the function for 2 minutes.

Comment: @Foxic What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it take a long time? Forever? It just exits? It prints the wrong value?

Comment: It just opens the command prompt window, and it's completely blank except for the underscore blinking at the start.

Comment: @Foxic Then I suggest you start looking into the ending condition of your inner loop. Are you sure that `j` will be `1` sometime? Or it might be that it just take a _very_ long time.

Comment: According to the collatz theory, yes, it'll always end up being 1. It doesn't seem to be processing either

Answer (score 1):

First, use `unsigned int` or `unsigned long long` as the variable type of `j` to increase the arithmetic range.

Then, in the loop, check for overflow.

```
 while (j!=1) {
    counter++;
    if (j % 2 == 0) {
        j >>= 1;
    } else {
        unsigned int j2 = j;
        j = (j*3) + 1;
        if (j2 > j) {
           return -1;  // or surround this with try/catch/throw exception
        }
   }
 }
```

With `int i;` the counter will overflow at i==113383;
and with `unsigned int i;` at 159487. If these are not checked, there's a possibility of infinite loop.